# Verilog - Trouble timing signals to module

Tags: verilog

I am having some trouble understanding why I am getting different results with the register module below.

```
module register (clk, rst, ld, din, dout);
   input clk;
   input rst;
   input ld;
   input [3:0] din;
   output reg [3:0] dout;

   always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
      if(rst) dout  = 4'b0;
      else if(ld) dout <= din;
      else dout <= dout;
   end

endmodule // rgister

module controller(clk, rst, ldI);
   input  clk;
   input  rst;
   output ldI;

   reg [2:0]   ps, ns;

   always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
      if(rst) ps <= 3'b0;
      else ps <= ns;
   end

   always @(ps) begin
      case(ps)
    3'b000 : ns <= 3'b001;
    3'b001 : ns <= 3'b010;
    3'b010 : ns <= 3'b011;
    3'b011 : ns <= 3'b100;
    3'b100 : ns <= 3'b101;
    3'b101 : ns <= 3'b110;
    3'b110 : ns <= 3'b111;
    3'b111 : ns <= 3'b000;
      endcase // case (ps)
   end // always @ (ps)

   assign ldI = (ps == 3'b001) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

endmodule // reg_controller

module datapath (clk, rst, ldI, din);
   input clk;
   input rst;
   input ldI;
   input [3:0] din;

   register Ireg (clk, rst, ldI, din);

endmodule

module top (clk, rst, din);
   input clk;
   input rst;
   input [3:0] din;

   wire        ldI;

   datapath   dp (clk, rst, ldI, din);
   controller cp (clk, rst, ldI);

endmodule // top

module tb;
   reg clk, rst;
   reg [3:0] din;
   reg       ld;

   initial begin
      rst = 1'b1;
      clk = 1'b0;
      din = 4'b0;
      ld  = 1'b0;
   end

   top      uut (clk, rst, din);
   register r   (clk, rst, ld, din);

   always #5 clk = ~clk;

   initial begin
      #21 rst = 1'b0;
      din = 4'h1;
      @(posedge clk);
      din = 4'h2;
      ld = 1'b1;
      @(posedge clk);
      ld = 1'b0;
      din = 4'h3;
      @(posedge clk);
      din = 4'h4;
      @(posedge clk);
      din = 4'h5;

      #50;

      $finish;
   end // initial begin


endmodule
```

Here is the wave output:
[image]

In the waves above, the blue is 'r' in the tb and the green is the Ireg in the datapath. I have stripped out most of what was in the datapath and controller to narrow down this timing problem that I am having.

I would like to have Ireg contain the value 2. What adjustments can I make to have this? I have tried using the negedge of the clock in the register module nad it works, but I don't feel this is the correct solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `tb` module. You have blocking assignments to your inputs on `@(posedge clk)` which produces races in your register. Use non-blocking assignments in your tesbench as well, or change to the `negedge`